# Ladybug camera issue when runing Error: Failed to initialize stream (Operation failed)

Tags: linux, camera, ros

I am trying to run a multi camera called Ladybug 
when I run this command, I detect the camera but I got a message error in the end.

```
herezac@zac:~/Downloads/ladybug-1.14.3.9_amd64/usr/src/ladybug
/src/LadybugRecorderConsole$ sudo LadybugRecorderConsoleLoading configuration 
from /etc/ladybug/LadybugRecorderConsole.xml

*** Configuration ***
Camera Configuration
Data format: JPEG (8-bit)
Frame rate: 10
Use auto frame rate: Yes
JPEG quality: 80%
GPS Configuration
Use GPS: No
Port: 4
Device name: dev/ttyACM0
Baud rate: 115200
Refresh interval (ms): 1000
Stream Configuration
Destination directory: .


Cameras detected: 1

Camera information: 
Base s/n: 15295511
Head s/n: 15295511
Model: Ladybug5 LD5-U3-51S5C-44
Sensor: Sony ICX655 (2/3" 2048x2448 CCD)
Vendor: Point Grey Research
Bus / Node: 0 / 0

Error: Failed to initialize stream (Operation failed)
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue so I can run the camera correctly? 
thanking you in advance

Comment: did verify your baud rate and stream config ?

Comment: finally it works. it was a problem with the camera, i just changed the USB port and it works.